# How to resolve an append issue to a csv file in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with adding some text to a csv file, my text is appending but it is appending to the previous line and not a new line. I also get a type error saying System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. This is obviously to do with the append issue but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any ideas?

here is the output in the csv file

University,0

Groceries,1

Other,2

Gaming,3Pets,4

Thanks in advance :)

Controller

```
// GET: Category/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Category/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category category)
    {
        try
        {
            TodolistRepository.AddCategory(category.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

.cs file

```
public static bool AddCategory(string category, int catId = 0)
    {
        int newIdentifier = catId;

        if (newIdentifier == 0)
        {
            int maxIdentifier = _listOfCategories.Max(x => x.Identifier);
            newIdentifier = ++maxIdentifier;
        }

        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_categoriesfile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    var line = $"{category},{newIdentifier.ToString()}";
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                    writer.Flush();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

 public static void ReadCategoriesFromFile()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_categoriesfile))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] fields = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                _listOfCategories.Add(new Category
                {
                    Name = fields[0],
                    Identifier = Int32.Parse(fields[1])
                });
            }
        }
    }
    //Gets all the categories in the List
    public static List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        ReadCategoriesFromFile();
        _listOfCategories = _listOfCategories.OrderBy(x => x.Identifier).ToList();
        return _listOfCategories;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add newLine"\r\n" character end of line where you addCategory. if you want to check if there is a line without newLine character read line first.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. I think the issue is with how it is appending the new line

Comment: try this way 
string newLine = "\r\n";
line = newLine + $"{category},{newIdentifier.ToString()}";
or you can add new line at last.

Comment: writeline adds a new line by default. I tried your method and as I thought the index is out of bounds of the array. There is something with my logic but thanks for the ideas mate